# Is this correct: "A strong voice for your interests"

Tags: word-usage

We choose "**For a strong voice for your interests**" as a slogan for a trade union election.

Is this correct English? It sounds strange to me, especially "interests" in this context. Would "Concerns" be a possible alternative?

What do you think?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: **interests** is a close synonym for **concerns**.  It does not sound strange. **concerns** would be a viable alternative.  We can voice concerns.  We can give voice to concerns.  We can be a voice for someone's concerns.

Comment: I think "A strong voice for your interests" would be better. When you say "*For* a strong voice for your interests", I expect some phrase to follow it. Also repetitive "for" sounds odd.

Answer (score 1):

As user3169 commented, this is better:

> A strong voice for your interests

The first "for" is just confusing. "Interests" is better suited and broader than "concerns" (although similar).

Also, slogans should be as short as possible, while including / transmitting a maximum of meaning.